# Let $f$ be a holomorphic function in the unit Disk D with $f(0) = f'(0)=0$, when will $g$ be constant multiples of $f$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function in the unit Disk D with $f(0) = f'(0)=0$, $g(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(\frac{z}{n})$, when will $g$ be constant multiples of $f$? $g$ so defined is an anlytic function by Wierstrass theorem. What will be the next step then?

Comment: certainly if $f(z)=az^k,k\ge 2$ is a monomial

Comment: Why is that true?

Comment: $g(z)=\sum_1^\infty a(z/n)^k=az^k\sum_1^\infty 1/n^k=C_k f(z)$, where $C_k<\infty$ is some constant.

Comment: But how will you show that is the only possible situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(z) = \sum_{k=2}^\infty a_k z^k$ is the Maclaurin expansion of $f$, then $$g(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f(z/n) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=2}^\infty a_k (z/n)^k = \sum_{k=2}^\infty a_k \zeta(k) z^k $$
(the double sum converging absolutely if $|z|<1$).

Since $\zeta(k)$ is a strictly decreasing function of $k > 1$, $g$ won't be a constant multiple of $f$ unless there is at most one nonzero $a_k$.